# Is there a standard way for getting the media mount path (like /media/user, /run/media/user...)?

Tags: mount, fhs, removable-storage, xdg, lsb

In an application, I need to find out where removable media is mounted. On Ubuntu, this happens in `/media/username/` . On Arch, it is `/run/media/username/` . On other systems, its just `/media/` etc.

There seems to be no `XDG` environment variable for this path. So I wonder, is this standardized anywhere? The FHS only specifies that there must be a /media directory, not how to find out that directory.

Comment: On Arch, it depends entirely on the automounter you install: udisks or the newer udisks2; they use different directories...

Comment: Oh, so this is enforced by udisks then. Thanks, I did not realize that.